# Extract several portions in a log file using a keyword from a list in a text file

Tags: python

I already read some ways on how to extract text from file but I'm having issues with the code that I implemented.

Goal: To collect certain parts in a log file using keywords (commands) which are located in a text file. In the sample data below. I want to extract output of `Command1`, `Command2`, etc. Extraction of text will be stopped each time `Command Executed` is encountered, but will continue until end of file to check if there is additional occurrence of the command. Please note that each command can be repeated but with different parameters.

Later on, I want to save the extracted data in separate files using the command as file name.

Log file:

```
Command1 Parameter=x  
Command1 contents  
Command1 contents  
Command Executed  
line that is not important  
line that is not important  
Command1 Parameter=y  
Command1 contents  
Command1 contents  
Command Executed  
line that is not important  
line that is not important  
Command2 Parameter=x  
Command2 contents  
Command2 contents  
Command Executed  
line that is not important  
line that is not important  
Command2 Parameter=y  
Command2 contents  
Command2 contents  
Command Executed  
line that is not important  
line that is not important
```

Command file:

```
Command1  
Command2  
Command3  
etc.
```

Code:

I already found the solution including output logging in a separate file. Here is the working code.

```
keyfile = "COMMAND_LIST.TXT"
testfile = "LOGFILE.TXT"

keys = [key for key in (line.strip() for line in open(keyfile)) if key]



copy = False
for key in keys:
    with open(testfile) as x:
        for line in x:

            if key in line:
                copy = True

            if copy:
                # print(line,end="")
                OUTPUT=line
                print(OUTPUT,end="")
                FILE=open("filepath"+key+".txt", "a", newline='')
                FILE.write(OUTPUT)
                FILE.close()

            if "COMMAND EXECUTED" in line:
                copy = False
```

Comment: Alright, have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you reset `lines = []` each time you change the command that you're looking for. You might want to read all the commands first and then process the logfile in a single pass. Here's how you can do it:

```py
with open('command_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Create a dict {command: [list of command outputs]}
    command_outputs = {command: [] for command in f.read().splitlines()}

with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as source:
    read_lines = False
    for line in source.read().splitlines():

        first_word = line.split()[0]      # extract the first word
        if first_word in command_outputs: # if first_word is in dict keys
            read_lines = True
            current_command = first_word

        if read_lines:
            # append current line to according list
            command_outputs[current_command].append(line)

        if "Command Executed" in line:
            read_lines = False

# Output
for command, source_lines in command_outputs.items():
    print(f'{command}:')
    for line in source_lines:
        print(f'\t{line}')
```

If you are unfamiliar with [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), they are just containers which can be indexed with some keys (in this case - `str` values) to access values (in this case - `list` 's).
At the end of the program, you've got your lines of source code in the `command_outputs` dictionary. They can be accessed like this: `command_output['Command1']`.

Note that I'm using `f.read().splitlines()` construction to avoid having `\n` carriage return symbols at the end of each line.

The output of the program:

```
Command1:
    Command1 Parameter=x
    Command1 contents
    Command1 contents
    Command Executed
    Command1 Parameter=y
    Command1 contents
    Command1 contents
    Command Executed
Command2:
    Command2 Parameter=x
    Command2 contents
    Command2 contents
    Command Executed
    Command2 Parameter=y
    Command2 contents
    Command2 contents
    Command Executed
Command3:
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!I appreciate your time on looking on to this. I already have a working code. Thanks again for the tip and I hope you will continue to support other beginner with this programming language!